# Remove nested relations from API explorer (swagger)

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I have `Application` model with following relation:

```
  @belongsTo(() => Ido)
  idoId: string;


export interface ApplicationRelations {
  ido?: IdoWithRelations;
}

export type ApplicationWithRelations = Application & ApplicationRelations;
```

`Application` repository looks like this:

```
  export class ApplicationRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  Application,
  typeof Application.prototype.id,
  ApplicationRelations
> {
  public readonly user: BelongsToAccessor<
    User,
    typeof Application.prototype.id
  >;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.db') dataSource: DbDataSource,
    @repository.getter('UserRepository')
    protected userRepositoryGetter: Getter<UserRepository>,
  ) {
    super(Application, dataSource);
    this.user = this.createBelongsToAccessorFor('user', userRepositoryGetter);

    this.inclusionResolvers.delete('ido');
  }
}
```

And the following relation in `IDO` model:

```
 @hasMany(() => Application)
  applications: Application[];
```

In `post /ido` in swagger i am getting this example for creating:

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "status": "string",
      "createdAt": 0,
      "idoId": "string",
      "userId": "string",
      "ido": {
        "applications": [
          {
            "status": "string",
            "createdAt": 0,
            "idoId": "string",
            "userId": "string",
            "ido": {
              "applications": [
                "string"
              ],
}
```

**Is there any ways to remove the duplicate and kind of curricular relation for `ido` in `application` from swagger?** Or this doesn't really matter and i can just manually delete all fields above the first application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This answer was copied over from https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/discussions/8536#discussioncomment-2655375.

OpenAPI/Swagger is at the REST layer, which means you'll need to look inside the respective REST Controller, which would have something similar to this:

```js
@post('...')
function create(
  @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Application, {
            title: 'NewApplication',
            exclude: ['id'],
          }),
        },
      },
    })
)
```

You can modify it as such to exclude relations:

```
@post('...')
function create(
  @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Application, {
            title: 'NewApplication',
            exclude: ['id'],
+          includeRelations: false,
          }),
        },
      },
    })
)
```

An alternative is to use `exclude`.

More info can be found in the API docs: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository-json-schema.getjsonschemaref.html